# Creating a Donut Chart in R using Highcharts

Tags: r, highcharts

I am trying to create a donut chart with some interactive-ness in R using `highcharts` library.

I have achieved a pie chart like below:

```
highchart() %>% 
  hc_add_series(type = "pie", data = age, hcaes(Age, Mean_percentage_viewed), 
                size = "60%", name = "Mean Percentage viewed", center = c(50, 50), 
                dataLabels = list(distance = -50, 
                                  formatter = JS("function () {
                                                  return this.y > 5 ? this.point.name : null;
  }"))) %>% 
  hc_title(text = "Age group share")
```

[image]

Is there a way to convert it into a donut chart? I could not find other examples that could transform into a donut chart.

```
> dput(age)
structure(list(Age = c("13–17 years", "18–24 years", "25–34 years", 
"35–44 years", "45–54 years", "55–64 years"), Views = c(0.38, 
70.01, 20.2, 6.91, 2.37, 0.13), Mean_view_duration = c("0:01:51", 
"0:02:25", "0:02:42", "0:02:58", "0:02:57", "0:02:23"), Mean_percentage_viewed = c(21.71, 
21.23, 24.31, 26.36, 24.94, 19.27), Watch.Time.Hours = c(0.28, 
67.14, 21.58, 8.11, 2.76, 0.12)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an `innerSize` with `hc_plotOptions` like this:

```r
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)
highchart() %>% 
  hc_add_series(type = "pie", data = age, hcaes(Age, Mean_percentage_viewed), 
                size = "60%", name = "Mean Percentage viewed", center = c(50, 50), 
                innerSize="50%",
                dataLabels = list(distance = -50, 
                                  formatter = JS("function () {
                                                  return this.y > 5 ? this.point.name : null;
  }"))) %>% 
  hc_title(text = "Age group share") %>%
  hc_plotOptions(
    innersize="50%", 
    startAngle=90, 
    endAngle=90,
    center=list('50%', '75%'),
    size='110%')
```

[image: ![](https://i.imgur.com/Rz2S72N.png)]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>